# $.post work only with alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When i call function with alert is working parfectly :

```
function post() {
    var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
    var cs = $('#cs').val(); $.post('a.php' {postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs});
    alert("The function work");
}
```

And the html form like this :

```
<form action="b.php" method="post" onsubmit="return post()">
```

The problem is when i remove alert from function the $.post doesnt work :

```
function post() {
    var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
    var cs = $('#cs').val(); $.post('a.php' {postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs});
}
```

Pls help :)

Comment: You are missing `return false;`

Answer (score 4):

Since `post()` doesn't have a `return` statement, the `onsubmit` function ends up returning `undefined`.

Since it doesn't return `false`, it doesn't cancel the normal behaviour of the form. Consequently, the form submits and unloads the page before the Ajax request resolves.

Putting in an `alert` delays the page unload until you click *OK*, which gives time for the Ajax request to resolve.

`return false` from the `post` function to cancel the normal submission of the form instead.

Comment: i try it but doesnt work <form action="b.php" method="post" onsubmit="return post(); return false;">

Comment: You should be retuning false from the function.  `function post() { /* your code */ return false; }`

Comment: @Sharondelmar — Putting a second return statement after the first one in the `onsubmit` function won't have any effect, it will never be reached because the function has already returned. As I said, you need to return from the `post` function.

Comment: When i use function post() { /* your code */ return false; }  submit doesnt work in action="b.php" !! thank u :)