# When i remove alert from code $.post doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

When i call function with alert is working parfectly :

```
function post() {
    var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
    var cs = $('#cs').val(); $.post('a.php',{postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs});
    alert("The function work");
}
```

And the html form like this :

```
<form action="b.php" method="post" onsubmit="return post()">
```

The problem is when i remove alert from function the $.post doesnt work :

```
function post() {
    var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
    var cs = $('#cs').val(); $.post('a.php',{postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs});
}
```

Pls help :)

Comment: It is not at all a good practice to ask same question multiple times. A question by you is already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694364/post-work-only-with-alert-pls-help

Comment: you forgot `,` after `a.php` in `$.post('a.php', {postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs});`

Comment: Your `post()` function does not return anything, so the default would be `undefined`

Comment: Add "return false" before post function close